# The maximum limit of cell while reading maximum 1 cells

Tags: java, excel, csv, apache-poi, opencsv

I have a problem with apache poi.
We are trying to make a dictionary with a database in excel so we are using apache poi to connect Java with excel. And when we try to add a new row to our excel when we save it we get an error. Here is the code part that gives us the error if more coded needed I'll give them.

```
public void cvsToExcel() throws IOException, InvalidFormatException{

    try{



    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("table.csv"),'$');
    String[] line;
    CreationHelper helper = ExcelBase.workbook.getCreationHelper();
    Sheet firstSheet = ExcelBase.workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    CellStyle cellStyle = ExcelBase.workbook.createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setDataFormat(helper.createDataFormat().getFormat("yyyy.mm.dd"));

    int r = 0;
    line = reader.readNext();
    while(line != null){
        org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row row = firstSheet.createRow(r++);

        for(int i = 0; i < line.length; i++){
             if(i == 0 || i == 11){
                try{
                    Cell c = row.createCell(i);
                    c.setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC);
                    c.setCellValue(Integer.parseInt(line[i]));
                    //row.createCell(i).setCellValue(Integer.parseInt(line[i]));
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }else if(i == 1){
                try{
                    String[] strTmp = line[i].split("-");
                    Date tmpDate = new Date(Integer.parseInt(strTmp[0])-1900,Integer.parseInt(strTmp[1]),Integer.parseInt(strTmp[2]));

                    Cell c = row.createCell(i);
                    c.setCellValue(HSSFDateUtil.getExcelDate(tmpDate));

                    c.setCellStyle(cellStyle);


                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }

            else{
                System.out.println("Row: " + row.getRowNum() + " Cell:" + i);
                row.createCell(i).setCellValue(line[i]);
            }
        }

        line = reader.readNext();

    }
    saveToXLSX();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Everyting is imported so that is not the problem.
Thanks for the help in advance I hope you guys can help me out :D

EDIT: I forgot the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The maximum length of cell contents (text) is 32,767 characters
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.setCellValue(XSSFCell.java:436)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.setCellValue(XSSFCell.java:417)
at hu.itsh.gyakorlat.szotar.io.excel.SaveActions.cvsToExcel(SaveActions.java:138)
at hu.itsh.gyakorlat.szotar.io.excel.SaveActions.fullSave(SaveActions.java:166)
at hu.itsh.gyakorlat.szotar.ui.actions.ActionSaveDb$1.doInBackground(ActionSaveDb.java:36)
at hu.itsh.gyakorlat.szotar.ui.actions.ActionSaveDb$1.doInBackground(ActionSaveDb.java:1)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Which code is in line 138 of  `SaveActions.java` - `SaveActions.java:138`?

Comment: row.createCell(i).setCellValue(helper.createRichTextString(line[i]));

Comment: Then `line[i]` contains a string having more than 32,767 characters. That does not fit into one `Excel` cell, see [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3).

Comment: Okay it worked I can't even think what word was in the cell it decided to die... Thank you for the help! :)